# Do Identical dimensions and inclusion imply equivalence for smooth manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $N$ and $M$ be two smooth manifolds with the same dimension $n$ and let $x \in N$. If we assume that  $N \subseteq M$  then how to prove or disprove that $N$ and $M$ are the same manifold in a neighborhood of $x$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the very least, you need $M$ connected. Does "manifold" = "manifold without boundary"? Are you assuming $N, M$ closed?

Comment: I see, I am going to modify the question,

Comment: What do you mean by "are the same manifold"?

Comment: I mean the manifold are identical.

Comment: Yes, the manifols are locally equivalent.

Comment: Isn't this just the definition of submanifold?  Since they have the same dimension, the charts will be diffeo to the same Euclidean space.

Comment: yes, the chart must diffeo in the same Euclidean space. So $N$ and $M$ must be diffeomorphic, right?

Comment: No, @jaogye, because you assumed $x\in N$. Take $N$ to be an open subset of $M$. For example, you could take $N$ to be a circle and $M$ to be a union of two circles. Or $N$ to be an open hemisphere and $M$ the entire sphere, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin  but they are still each locally diffeo, no?   (A nbhd of one is diffeo to a nbhd of the other.)

Comment: The precise question isn’t that clear to me.

Comment: yes, $N$ and $M$ are locally diffeo at $x \in N$,